# I am having a type mismatch error with this reference

Tags: vba, excel, for-loop, if-statement

Here is the code I am having an issue with. I am simply trying to input the value "0" into column G when the value in the corresponding row in column B is Deuterium. The debugger tells me my error lies with the line containing the If statement.

```
For i = 3 To 30
    If Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, 2) = "Deuterium" Then
        Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, 7).Value = 0
    End If
Next
```

screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Are you sure the `WorkSheet` is named "Master PEC"? Or is that the name of the `Workbook`?

Comment: @brax Then the error should have been "out of range"?

Comment: Do you have errors like (#N/A, #Div/0, #Value,...) in the range to be checked?

Comment: yes. the range has #Value! in it @ScottCraner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You cannot equate an error with a string.

You will need to add a check to not test the errors.

```
For i = 3 To 30
    If Not IsError(Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, 2)) Then
        If Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, 2) = "Deuterium" Then
            Worksheets("Master PEC").Cells(i, 7).Value = 0
        End IF
    End If
Next
```

Comment: Thank you! I am now receiving the error that my for loop has not been initialized